# Send an Email on Contacts

Tags: lightning, email, enhanced-emails

I am using Enhanced Emails.

My use case is as follows:
When on the contact record, if the user clicks the send email button, they can send the email, and the "Related to:" field is filled out with the appropriate contact record ID. This is then reflected on the activity history (probably the most important part)

This works perfectly fine on any other object, say on an Account, if you send an email on the account object to someone, it is reflect on the "Related To:", filling it out with the AccountId and is put into the activity history.

The issue is that Contact doesn't appear to be something you can select on the "Related To:" field. Is there anyway to add this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For `Task`, the Related To field is known by API Name `WhatId` and per the [Task Object doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm?search_text=task), it must be:

> Type reference
>
> Properties
>   Create, Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort, Update
>
> Description
>   The **WhatId represents nonhuman objects** such as accounts, opportunities, campaigns, cases, or custom objects. WhatIds are polymorphic. Polymorphic means a WhatId is equivalent to the ID of a related object. The label is Related To ID.

Thus, `WhatId` is never a Lead or Contact or User

The Task.WhoId represents the Lead/Contact or User